# Can we link two java files on single label

Tags: java, html, swing

I am making a jlabel and there are two different words that are separated by `'<br>'` element of HTML.

I want to link both the words with two different java files which exist in the same package.

```
JLabel day1 = new JLabel("<html><a href='java_class1.java'>1</a><br><font color=red size=2><a href='java_class2.java'>" + rupees + "</a></font><html>");
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  How is the result different from what you expected?

Comment: I am not able to link java files when I am d oing click any link.

Comment: Are you saying that you expected clicking on an anchor would show the linked file in your JLabel?

Comment: No, I have two more Java files "java_class1.java" and "java_class2.java" when I will click on first anchor then "java_class1.java" file should open and when I will click on second anchor then "java_class2.java" file should open<br/> But currently I am not able to open these files

Comment: JLabel is not a full HTML renderer.  It just paints HTML, it doesn’t actually implement anchor functionality.  Use a [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) for that.

Comment: Hi, I tried the following code: **"day1 = new JEditorPane("<html><a href='product_entries.java'>1</a><html>");"** and found following error: **"[java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <html><a href='product_entries.java'>1</a><html>]"**

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation for that constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: *"Thank you Vikrant.."* 1) A person that edits a question cannot be tagged. 2) The only person who has offered useful advice is @VGR. If there is anything you don't understand in what they are telling / asking you, you should be asking for clarification. Have you checked that constructor yet?